# How/why does this globbing expression work?

Tags: bash, wildcards

In one of my bash scripts I needed to obtain the last part of a colon delimited string. For example I needed to grab the numeric `289283` value from the following value:

```
OK: DriveC-ReadBytesPerSec: 289283
```

After some trial and error I arrived at the following:

```
READRESULT="OK: DriveC-ReadBytesPerSec: 289283"
echo ${READRESULT#*:*:*}
```

Which outputs `289283`.

The problem is that whilst it gets the job done, I don't fully understand why `${READRESULT#*:*:*}` produces the correct result.

Can anyone explain how this globbing expression works?

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `${READRESULT##*: }`, to strip everything until the last colon followed by a space. Note that `${READRESULT#*:*:*}` has a leading space, which could cause trouble down the line; and as peth writes the last `*` isn't matching anything. `${READRESULT#*:*: }` is probably what you meant to write.

Comment: @gilles - as I said, it was pure trial and error whilst under some time pressure :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From `man bash`:

> ${parameter#word}
>   ${parameter##word}
>
> Remove matching prefix pattern.  The word is expanded  to  produce  a  pattern
>   just  as  in  pathname expansion.  If the pattern matches the beginning of the
>   value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the expanded value  of
>   parameter  with  the shortest matching pattern (the `#` case) or the longest
>   matching pattern (the `##` case) deleted.

Your pattern is `*:*:*`, and `bash` will try to remove the shortest matching prefix:

- `OK:` for the first `*:`
- `DriveC-ReadBytesPerSec:` for the second `*:`
- and nothing for the last `*`, because it goes for the shortest match.

Compare:

```
$ # shortest match without surplus *
$ echo ${READRESULT#*:*:}
289283
$ # going for longest match now; the last * will swallow the number
$ echo ${READRESULT##*:*:*}

$ # longest match without the last *
$ echo ${READRESULT##*:*:}
289283
$ # no need to repeat *: because * matches everything before the last : anyway
$ echo ${READRESULT##*:}
289283
```